# Question about hMail server configurations, where to ask it?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have remote Windows server and I want to set [**hMail**](https://www.hmailserver.com/) server to work on it well, i.e creating emails accounts @mydomain.com and make them available via smtp and pop3 or imap for mail clients such as Mozilla Thunderbird.

Where should I ask this question:

1. [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)
2. [Super User](http://superuser.com)
3. [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: @gnat: Answer there doesn't mention any of the three sites in this question. This question isn't really about CS at all.

Comment: @NathanTuggy good catch, thanks (retracted dupe vote)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't actually know hMail but based on the fact that you ask about the server side configuration of the product I expect Server Fault would be the best candidate.

A rough search (excluding Stack Overflow) [confirmed](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=hmail+-site%3Astackoverflow.com) that Server Fault does have some of those questions.

Before you ask there check their [help center](https://serverfault.com/help) and study their [What is on topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), this rule I believe matches your question

> - deployment to and management of third-party provided information technology platforms

Some meta sites are open for advice if a specific question is on-topic for the main site. For the meta's that offer that option create your actual question you want to ask and then post on [Server Fault Meta](https://meta.serverfault.com/)  while asking if that specific question is indeed a good fit or ask in their chat, which is even less invasive. Here is an [example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322904) of such question on MSO.

I'm sure Webmasters will not take it. They declare System and network administration as off-topic.

For Super User I would follow the same procedure as for Server Fault.

Comment: I agree with all in this answer except the idea of posting a test question on a site's Meta.

Comment: Good, I will check the documents, that you regarded, of Server Fault.

Comment: My experience is mostly on smaller sites like [gis.se] and [genealogy.se] and it may be a personal preference but I would rather a user post where they think is on-topic (preferably by consulting the on-topic pages) and just coming to Meta to clarify why not if their question gets closed.

Comment: It should usually be a single step process but chat is an option too.

Comment: I like that much better and have now upvoted.